# Single Phase Active PWM Rectifier using MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, pwm, ac-dc, bidirectional

I am using this H-Bridge Configuration to make active PWM rectification to control the output average Voltage by controlling the Modulation Index.
Here is the circuit diagram and the pulses of each MOSFET, using a resistive load for simplicity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvWFUC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pulses of each switch is something like this:
where **Q1 and Q2 are Modulating** during the +ve half cycle, then during the negative half cycle, **Q3 and Q4 are Modulating**

[image]

The output should be like this:
[image]

but what I get from simulation of this circuit in SIMULINK is not close:

[image]

Where is the problem ? is it in the gate pulses ? or is the whole circuit not connected right ?

Comment: Consider the internal body diodes of the MOSFETS. They represent a bridge rectifier, even without any gate drive. Q4 is shorted in your schematic.

Comment: You mean I could use the internal body diodes to do the rectification process ?
And how is Q4 shorted ?

Comment: No, I mean you cannot avoid, that the body diodes do the rectification without any significant option to control this via PWM.

Comment: Then I will try to use IGBT instead of MOSFET as It does not have a body diode

Answer (score 0):

You are not measuring the output voltage correctly. You have inadvertently got some ground reference on the AC supply (an irrelevant node for what you want). You should put the 0 volts/ground reference on one terminal of the load resistor (R1 in your first picture). I can see it works but you can't because you haven't got the visibility due to the reference node being badly/inexpertly placed.